# SQL - Make Join Query Faster

Tags: sql, join, select

I've made a query that selects 2 values from 2 tables. I need to run this query about 32 times when a visitor visits my website. This makes the page quite slow (it takes over 5 seconds to fully load).

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT tmdb.name, patch.sfo_title
FROM tmdb
RIGHT JOIN patch
ON tmdb.titleid = CONCAT(patch.cusa, '_00')
WHERE cusa = :titleid
LIMIT 1
```

is there any way to make this query faster? The query isn't the biggest operation if I look at it, so I'm not really sure why it's so slow?

Comment: Running a query 32 times for a request is in itself suspicious. Can you try to reduce how many times it's ran? Or run a single query with all the results together?

Comment: @Alejandro I will try that now

Comment: Why not run a single query that returns 32 rows?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query as a `left join` (out of preference, not performance):

```
SELECT t.name, p.sfo_title
FROM patch p LEFT JOIN
     tmdb t
     ON t.titleid = CONCAT(p.cusa, '_00')
WHERE p.cusa = :titleid
LIMIT 1;
```

Then for performance, I would recommend indexes on `patch(cusa, sfo_title)` and `t(titleid)`.

Note that the use of `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is suspicious, although you might have reasons for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tested it, however, the page load remains more than 5 seconds.

Comment: @AppelFlap . . . Even with the specified indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You are joining two tables based on a CALCULATED field?  No wonder it is slow.  I have no idea how your tables get maintained, but you need to get that concat'ed value of CUSA into the data base as a separate field and get it indexed, as Gordon Linoff suggested.  You could even maintain it through On Insert and On Update triggers.  Personally, I would examine why you have similar but different keys in your two tables and try to rationalize it down to one.  That Concat(CUSA, '_00' ) looks suspiciously like an opportunity to simplify the application.